# Newsletter, Outlook hangs "Contacting cdn.sstatic.net"

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, newsletter, cdn

Something in the Newsletter emails causes Microsoft Outlook to hang for about a minute when I try to open them.  This used to happen a while ago, then stopped happening (for the last few months?), today it's happening again (with the Programmers Weekly Newsletter).  This dialog appears:

[image]

And Outlook becomes unusable for a while:

[image]

What might be causing this?  I'm currently using Outlook 2013.  I used to have the problem with Outlook 2010 also.  (I don't get this kind of problem with any other emails.)

Comment: It looks like outlook doesn't understand the protocol-relative url. Instead it tries to reach a networksever over smb.

Comment: You might point out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303633/preventing-secure-insecure-errors-by-using-protocol-relative-urls-for-image-sour) to the makers of that newsletter.

Comment: Happening today with the Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter.. It's annoying because Outlook completely hangs for about 30 seconds or longer.  I can't be the only one subscribed to the newsletters and using Outlook!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix is rolling out as we speak. Turns out, many email clients don't support protocol-relative URLs.

One of the more entertaining side-effects is that some (like Gmail) will just strip protocol-relative URLs out entirely. This affected the styling and display of all of our newsletters.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: it looks like this has come back over this weekeend (running outlook 2016), now it's: \\cdn.sstatic.net\Sites\stackoverflow\img (not on newsletter, but on alert feeds)